# Cherry pick attributes from an object in a generic way

Tags: java, aggregation, soa

I want to build a data aggregator which calls multiple services and **extract some attributes** from their response and then build the aggregated object.

Please consider the below example:
To fetch order details, I need to make a call to **GetOrderDetails** API of OrderService, which returns below output (simplified one):

```
{
   statusCode: OK,
   orderDetails: {
      orderId: "order_id",
      offer: {
         offerId: "offer_id",
         offerType: "offer_type"
      },
      address: {
         addressId: "address_id",
         houseNo: "house_no",
         city: "city",
         state: "state"
      }
   }
}
```

Similarly, I need to make a call other services.

**Problem**
I need to build output object by cherry picking the attributes from the response of these services **without hard coding the logic** through getters of the concerned attributes.

I am planning to have a list of needed attributes and their respective paths stored as config and then extracting logic would be generic.

Well, config will look like:
**output_attribute: dotted_hierarchy_path**
orderId: orderDetails.orderId
addressId: orderDetails.address.addressId

So, my output object will be:

```
{
    orderId: <order_id>,
    addressId: <address_id>
}
```

If I have this kind of configuration, my java code would be generic i.e. it can cherry pick any attribute from any object.

To extract the required attributes, I am thinking is to traverse the dotted path and through Java Reflection get the value. But Java Reflection is slow.

**This is a practical world problem and hence want folks to put their valuable approaches.**

Comment: @Turing85: I have put up my approach to the problem through configuration which stores hierarchy through dotted path and Java Reflection. The ask here is to suggest a better approach if anyone has.

Comment: @Turing85: This is a practical world problem, can have multiple approaches, so want to discuss with the stackoverflow community. Thanks.

Comment: @Turing85: Done.

Comment: Thanks :) My comments will self-destruct shortly.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, reflection is slow and tricky. I wouldn't try to reimplement it from scratch but rather use existing libraries, such as [FasterXML/jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). And I wouldn't worry about performance for now.

In general, I would try to convert objects to nested maps. If you have access to plain jsons, you don't need to map them to objects, this way you skip reflection:

```
Map<String, Object> root = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

If you have to deal with objects, you can convert them to nested maps in a similar way:

```
Map<String, Object> root = objectMapper.convertValue(object, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

Getting values by dotted_hierarchy_path from the nested maps should be pretty easy.

Comment: I have kind of heavy objects, lot of fields, lots of hierarchies, etc., so using Map will be memory consuming. I know, map reduces the efforts solving this problem but at the cost of lot of memory for heavy objects. Thanks for your valuable approach :)

Comment: @Azim You might be right, but I would take the simplest approach just to implement a proof of concept. I think, that you will face more serious problems on the way, e.g. if you needed to extract a field from the object B, based on a value from the object A. You will end up with a kind of custom mini-language in your configuration, dotted hierarchy path won't suffice. Again, I would look for ready solutions, maybe JSONPath, etc. Or maybe some dynamic language like Groovy would be better here.

Comment: Yeah, I already looked into JSONPath and it seems to be a good solution to me. https://jsonpath.com/

Comment: Could you please include JSONPath and JSONPatch in your answer, so that I could accept it?